# using reserved word as entity name

Tags: c#, sql-server, nhibernate

I'm using NHibernate mapping by code with naming conventions to map my entities. Now I have following error

```
SQL error - Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'User'.:
```

I know this is reserved word and I'm wonder how can I use this name (User) as entity name in mapping by conventions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1204263/491243

Comment: Would you post your query? if `User` is a field's name you should put in [].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct way to deal with this in NHibernate is using [SQL Quoted Identifiers](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-quotedidentifiers).

Just wrap the table or column name in backticks and the `Dialect` will take care of using the right symbol for your database.

To make things easier, NHibernate provides a configuration setting that does this for you: set `hbm2ddl.keywords="auto-quote"` in an xml config file, or call `AutoQuoteKeywords()` when using loquacious.

Answer (score 10):

You can use it by wrapping it around square brackets as it is a reserved keyword in SQL SERVER:

`[User]`

The word `user` is a [reserved word](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa238507%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) in SQL Server. If you need to use it as a column name, put brackets around it. This goes for all table names and other user-defined names that happen to collide with keywords,

Example:

```
Select * from tbl where [User] = 'xyz'
```

Comment: While this works, it's **not** the recommended way to do it in NHibernate.

Comment: What's the recommended way then?

Answer (score 2):

If the brackets don't work, try this:

```
"`User`"
```